# GPS icon gets stable where as it should disappear after getting first fix

Tags: android

Having problem while getting location through GPS: When GPS gets first location, my GPS icon disappears and reappear after 1 minute this is normal, but in one device after getting first location GPS icon gets stable and remain stable till GPS gets out of range or I have to close the application, I am not getting this why this is happening?

Comment: The second behavior seems more normal to me. When you get steady signal, the icon stays there until all apps using the location have been closed, or the signal is not steady. This is the behavior on all my devices.

Comment: actually i have placed: mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MINIMUM_TIME, MINIMUM_DISTANCE, mlocListener); where minimum time=1 minute. thats y in other devices icon get disappear but on galaxy s it doesnt seem to work.